# Print a XpsDocument result in a corrupted PrintDialog

Tags: wpf, printing, xpsdocument

I have an issue with the printing of XPS documents. The first print works correctly but then the print dialog and the prints appears corrupted as you can see in that [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I32tQ.png).

I tried to use other overloads of the Write function such as the one using a DocumentPaginator as a parameter or the PrintDocument function of the print dialog but it didn't work either.

I noticed that the results depend on the choice of printer. Using the Microsoft XPS Document Writer works correctly but use a real printer or a PDF printer didn't.

Here's the simplest code that reproduces the issue :

```
public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    var printDialog = new PrintDialog();

    if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        PrintDocument(
            "xps_document_filename.xps",
            printDialog);
    }
}

private static void PrintDocument(string documentPath, PrintDialog printDialog)
{
    using (var xpsDocumentSource = new XpsDocument(documentPath, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        XpsDocumentWriter xpsDocumentWriter = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(printDialog.PrintQueue);
        xpsDocumentWriter.Write(xpsDocumentSource.GetFixedDocumentSequence());
    }
}
```

Comment: I seriously doubt this has anything to do with the xps document and everything to do with your OS.  Have you reproduced on a different machine?  If so, open a connect with microsoft, I'm sure they'd love to see this.

Comment: You're right when I try this code on my Win 10 machine using the PDF printer provided by default, it works but I can't change the machines on which my application will be deployed. Basically, I'm screwed...

Comment: Those machines are screwed.  If whoever is in charge of them refuses to reinstall/fix them, then *they* are the ones that are screwed.  There is **absolutely nothing** you can do in code to fix this.